# C++ How to fill up array from next available position in array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I've initialised an array that will be filled up with values during runtime though I cannot figure out how to assign the next available position in the array with a value. For example

```
int array[5];
for (int i=0; i<15; i++)
    if(i == 5 || i == 10)
        array[0] = i
```

I'd want the first value, 5 to be assigned to array[0] then the second value 10 to be assigned to array[1] etc. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: That was an example, not what I was actually trying to do. Thanks either way.

Comment: Learn [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here please.

Comment: Sir, learn how to read good questions please.

Comment: @fdghfgdhfghfghfghdfghdfghfg This, is certainly not a _good question_ regarding what's said in the help center article I pointed you. And other of your questions look the same train wreck.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have one more variable, `nextAvailablePosition`.

```
array[nextAvailablePosition++] = 5;
array[nextAvailablePosition++] = 10;
```

Or just use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fill your array with incrementing multiples of 5:

```
int array[5];
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    array[i] = (i+1) * 5;
}
```

If you want to alternate between 5 and 10:

```
int array[5];
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    array[i] = (i % 2 == 0) ? 5 : 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See that the array will content the numbers between 0 and 14, because you are using the < operator (i < 5), if you want between 0 and 15, use <=

The answer for the specific question is creating a new variable

```
int array[5];
int aux = 0; //New variable
for (int i=0; i<15; i++){
      if(i == 5 || i == 10){
             array[aux] = i;
             aux++; // aux = aux+1
      }
}
```

But in this case, the array will content the values of the i, it's not necessary to use the loop, you can do in this way:

```
array[0] = 5;
array[1] = 10;
```

But maybe what you really want is put in the array the integers multiples of 5, so in this case, you can note that:

A number multiple of 5 is a number that when divided by 5 left a remainder of 0, that is:

```
if (number % 5 == 0){
      //number is multiple of 5
}
```

So, if you want to put all numbers multiple of 5 betwen 0 and 15, what you can do is:

```
int array[5];
int aux = 0; //New variable
for (int i=0; i<=15; i++){ // <= to use 15 too
      if(i%5){
             array[aux] = i;
             aux++; // aux = aux+1
      }
}
```

Or a best way:

```
int value = 5;
int array[5];
int aux = 0;
while(value <= 15) {
    array[aux] = value;
    aux++;
    value += 5; // value = value+5
}
```